# Can oracle 10g can be the used for multi dimensional data warehouse?

Tags: oracle10g, data-warehouse

I am new to the data warehousing and was just curious to know if oracle 10g or MySql can be used for multi dimensional data warehouse or we can only use something like Hyperion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely use Oracle or MySQL for this. Here are some [data warehousing tips from Oracle themselves](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96520/logical.htm#97642).

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can find more interesting information about [Oracle Solution](http://www.oracle.com/us/solutions/datawarehousing/index.html) on their website.